# can't use onUpdate method on laravel 8

Tags: sql, laravel-8

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('author')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

onUpdate did not work??

Answer (score 0):

Please check like this.

```
$table->foreignId('author')->constrained()
      ->onUpdate('cascade')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```